# how to show 2 array in 1 foreach in laravel blade

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have 2 arrays to send to my front like below:

```
public function startreserve(Request $request){
    $checkbox = $request->input('d');
    foreach ( $request->input('d') as $values){
        $values = explode("-",$values);
        $date[] = $values[0];
        $price[] = $values[1];
    }
    return view('users.properties.reserve',compact('date','price'));
}
```

Here is what I wrote on my blade and its working fine but I want to show date and price together so I think I have to use 1 foreach and show them both so I wanna know if that's possible here is view:

```
 <div class="col-lg-12">
     @foreach($price as $prices)
        <div class="col-lg-2">{{$prices}}</div>
     @endforeach
     @foreach($date as $dates)
        <div class="col-lg-2">{{$dates}}</div>
     @endforeach
 </div>
```

Comment: What is wrong with conactenating prices and dates?

Comment: @B001ᛦ i just tried that but it shows  all dates first and then all prices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
@foreach($price as $key => $prices)
    <div class="col-lg-2">{{$prices}}</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">{{$date[$key]}}</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: thanks that did the job for me :) one more question is that can i count the index of each of them in controller ??? just to tell me how many days they selected

Comment: i did in question take a look in that i want to count the days

Answer (score 1):

you can use `for` loop on array as well

```
for($i-0;i<count($date);$i++){
  echo array_key_exists($i,$date)?$date[$i]:"";
  echo " ";
  echo array_key_exists($i,$price)?$price[$i]:"";
}
```

In `Blade`, you can do it like this

```
 @for ($i = 0; $i <count($date) ;$i++)
   {{ $date[$i] }} {{ $price[$i] }}
 @endfor
```

Answer (score 1):

If lengths of both arrays are same and keys are like 0,1,2.... you can use for loop instead of foreach.

```
@for($i=0; $i<count($prices); $i++)
   <div class="col-lg-2">{{$prices[$i]}}</div>
   <div class="col-lg-2">{{$dates[$i]}}</div>
@endfor
```

Comment: the variable passed is `$price`